# BubbleSort numeros aleatorios

Tags: c#, classificação, random

Os numeros são gerados aleatorios no vetor, porém quando chamo a funcao bublle para ordenar o resultado retorna 0. Alguem pode me ajudar????

```
using System;

namespace BubbleSort_CSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] vetor = new int[10];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Vetor Desordenado\n");
            for (int i = 0; i <= vetor.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Elemento: {0}", rnd.Next(1, 100));     
            }

            bubbleSort(vetor, vetor.Length);            
            Console.WriteLine("\nVetor Ordenado\n");

            for (int i = 0; i <= vetor.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Elemento: {0} ", vetor[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void bubbleSort(int[] vetor, int length)
        {
            int trocas = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < length - (i + 1); j++)
                {
                    if (vetor[j] > vetor[j + 1])
                    {
                        trocas = vetor[j];
                        vetor[j] = vetor[j + 1];
                        vetor[j + 1] = trocas;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Seu algoritmo de ordenação está funcionando perfeitamente. O problema é que **não existem elementos no array `vetor`**. No primeiro `for` os valores gerados apenas são mostrados no console, eles deveriam ser inseridos no array. Por isso no segundo `for` só é mostrado o valor 0, o array foi criado com 10 posições, mas nenhuma foi preechida com algum valor, ou seja, todos os valor *default* de `int`, que é 0.

Altere o primeiro `for` para:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++)
{
    vetor[i] = rnd.Next(1, 100); // Aqui adiciona o número gerado à posição i de vetor
    Console.WriteLine("Elemento: {0}", vetor[i]);     
}
```

#### Atenção

A condição dos dois laços `for` **está errada**, elas devem ser **`i < vetor.Length`** e não **`i <= vetor.Length`**. Da forma atual, no último laço o valor de **`i`** será 10 e o último índice do array é 9, isso vai causar um `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zZlTMe)

---

Código completo

```
using System;   

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] vetor = new int[10];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("Vetor Desordenado\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++)
        {
            vetor[i] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("Elemento: {0}", vetor[i]);     
        }

        bubbleSort(vetor, vetor.Length);            
        Console.WriteLine("\nVetor Ordenado-- \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Elemento: {0} ", vetor[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void bubbleSort(int[] vetor, int length)
    {
        int trocas = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
        {           
            for (int j = 0; j < length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (vetor[j] > vetor[j + 1])
                {
                    trocas = vetor[j];
                    vetor[j] = vetor[j + 1];
                    vetor[j + 1] = trocas;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom para arrumar o seu problema bastar fazer as seguintes alterações, 
no primeiro for já adicionar o item no vetor, e em vez de vetor.Length colocar vetor.Length -1 nos for, de forma geral o seu código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] vetor = new int[10];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("Vetor Desordenado\n");
        for (int i = 0; i <= vetor.Length-1; i++)
        {
            int aleatorio = rnd.Next(1, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("Elemento: {0}", aleatorio);
            vetor[i] = aleatorio;
        }

    bubbleSort(vetor, vetor.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("\nVetor Ordenado\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= vetor.Length-1; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Elemento: {0} ", vetor[i]);
    }
         Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void bubbleSort(int[] vetor, int length)
    {
        int trocas = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < length - (i + 1); j++)
            {
                if (vetor[j] > vetor[j + 1])
                {
                    trocas = vetor[j];
                    vetor[j] = vetor[j + 1];
                    vetor[j + 1] = trocas;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```